# Docker Swarm: Error response from daemon: error while validating Root CA Certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: docker, x509, docker-swarm, docker-engine

**OS**: CentOS 7 VM

Docker latest version

**Commands Executed:**

```
   1) docker swarm init
   2) docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-3iqtmbz55yvhxkahe2ncs7d9ebxzlzmw1pwhqzvmcemiolef63-3muc4qjs3mbvh53t8ktzzmb22 192.168.10.108:2377 
    Error: Error response from daemon: error while validating Root CA Certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

As you can see, swarm join is giving me this error. What is the reason for this error and where is it coming from?

Regards
Aditya

Comment: are you executing both commands on same machine or different ? Are you using any proxies?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Both are executed on different machines.

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: running into same problem despite including both "HTTP_PROXY" & "NO_PROXY"

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Nope. No proxies!

Comment: Fix the time on both machines so that they are in same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had similar issue because swarm init generated ca certificate with start date in future. Possibly due to ntp lag.

CA cert info may be acquired using following command:

```
docker swarm ca | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        ...
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: CN=swarm-ca
    Validity
        Not Before: Oct 24 20:25:00 2018 GMT
        Not After : Oct 19 20:25:00 2038 GMT
    Subject: CN=swarm-ca
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                ...
                ...
                ...
                ...
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            ...
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

You can see the range of validity is between Oct 24 20:25:00 2018 GMT and Oct 19 20:25:00 2038 GMT. If the machine trying to join the swarm doesn't have its clock in that interval, it will fail with that error.

Answer (score 5):

this error generate when time not sync in your nodes. 
after initial swarm

```
docker swarm init
```

you can see limitation time for swarm certificate with bellow command

```
docker swarm ca | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

your node time must be between

Validity
            Not Before: Feb 20 10:21:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Feb 15 10:21:00 2039 GMT

and for setting node time in linux can use 'timedatectl' command

for automatic sync time , you can use follow command in every node

```
timedatectl set-timezone asia/Tehran
timedatectl set-ntp on
```

and you can show all timezone with

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply deleted certificate and restarting service worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the same date on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the date and time was not synchronized between VMs where docker nodes were running:

The following commands helped me to overcome the issue:

```
systemctl stop ntpd ;  ntpdate *server* ; systemctl start ntpd
```

As [docs](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.1/ntpdate.htm) state:

> ntpdate sets the local date and time by polling the Network Time
>   Protocol (NTP) server(s) given as the server arguments to determine
>   the correct time

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and its work for me

- Change the time zone (GMT can be changed based on the time zone in the control node):

  timedatectl set-timezone GMT
- Change the format of the Date in the node machine

  date --set "Tue 2021-12-21 17:18:07 GMT"

Tip: Get the date format from the swarm master node by running this command

```
docker swarm ca | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep "Not Before"
```